# Disable submit button until form is valid in angular's reactive forms + onpush

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-reactive-forms

How to disable submit button on init and with **onpush**?

`form.invalid` doesn't work with onpush, it isn't changed to valid in a view until change detection run manually with MarkForCheck. I thought that statusChanges would fire change detection with async pipe, because it's an observable, but it doesn't emit a value until inputs are changed.

component:

```
@Component({
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    selector: "ab-sign-in",
    templateUrl: "./sign-in.template.html",
})
export class SignInComponent implements OnInit {
    public form: FormGroup;
    public invalid$: Observable<boolean>;

    constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    ) { }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
            email: ["", [Validators.required, emailValidator]],
            password: ["", Validators.required],
        });

        this.invalid$ = this.form.statusChanges
            .map((state) => state !== "VALID");
    }
}
```

html:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
    <input formControlName="email" type="email" />
    <input formControlName="password" type="password" />
    <button type="submit"
            [disabled]="invalid$ | async">
        LOG IN
    </button>
</form>
```

**here is the plunker:**

https://plnkr.co/edit/RMboNCrThQSZOskUuZSZ?p=preview

Comment: read [this blog](https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/)

Comment: I know how change detection works. How to retreive form status and disable button on init with onpush? Added plunker.

Comment: why not use form.invalid instead of $invalid?

Comment: lol, I'm an idiot. form.invalid works with onpush xD seems angular run change detection when form is changed under the hood. don't know how I missed that it works fine.